Why does this code use more and more memory over time?
Python: 3.11
Saxonche: 12.4.2
My website keeps consuming more and more memory until the server runs out of memory and crashes. I isolated the problematic code to the following script:
import gc
from time import sleep

from saxonche import PySaxonProcessor


xml_str = """
<root>
    <stuff>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac auctor ex. Nunc in tincidunt urna. Sed tincidunt eros lacus, sed pulvinar sem venenatis et. Donec euismod orci quis pellentesque sagittis. Donec at tortor in dui mattis facilisis. Pellentesque vel varius lectus. Nunc sed gravida risus, ac finibus elit. Etiam sollicitudin nunc a velit efficitur molestie in ac lectus. Donec vulputate orci odio, sit amet hendrerit odio rhoncus commodo.</stuff>
    <stuff>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac auctor ex. Nunc in tincidunt urna. Sed tincidunt eros lacus, sed pulvinar sem venenatis et. Donec euismod orci quis pellentesque sagittis. Donec at tortor in dui mattis facilisis. Pellentesque vel varius lectus. Nunc sed gravida risus, ac finibus elit. Etiam sollicitudin nunc a velit efficitur molestie in ac lectus. Donec vulputate orci odio, sit amet hendrerit odio rhoncus commodo.</stuff>
    <stuff>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac auctor ex. Nunc in tincidunt urna. Sed tincidunt eros lacus, sed pulvinar sem venenatis et. Donec euismod orci quis pellentesque sagittis. Donec at tortor in dui mattis facilisis. Pellentesque vel varius lectus. Nunc sed gravida risus, ac finibus elit. Etiam sollicitudin nunc a velit efficitur molestie in ac lectus. Donec vulputate orci odio, sit amet hendrerit odio rhoncus commodo.</stuff>
</root>
"""

while True:
    print('Running once...')
    with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:
        proc.parse_xml(xml_text=xml_str)

    gc.collect()
    sleep(1)

This script consumes memory at a rate of about 0.5 MB per second. The memory usage does not plateau after a while. I have logs showing that memory usage continues to grow for hours until the server runs out of memory and crashes.
Other things I tried that aren't shown above:

Using a PyDocumentBuilder to parse the XML instead of a PySaxonProcessor. It didn't appear to change anything.
Deleting the Saxon processor and the return value of parse_xml() using the del Python keyword. No change.

I have to use Saxon instead of lxml because I need XPath 3.0 support.
What am I doing wrong? How do I parse XML using Saxon in a way that doesn't leak?

A few folks have suggested that instantiating the PySaxonProcessor once before the loop will fix the leak. It doesn't. This still leaks:
with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:
    while True:
        print('Running once...')
        proc.parse_xml(xml_text=xml_str)

        gc.collect()
        sleep(1)


Saxonica has a public support site here

As a note, you say you need XPath 3 support, for Python there is also https://pypi.org/project/elementpath/ to provide that.

Also note that with Saxon, be it the Java, the .NET version or the SaxonC version, the Processor object is the one you should usually create once and cache it, how you do that depends on your environment, but for your Python web site, if the used framework provides some application cache, look into storing the PySaxonProcessor in there, if supported.

This does look like a bug as mentioned in other posts. The workaround is to create the PySaxonProcessor before the while loop. You can create as `proc = PySaxonProcessor(license=False)

@ond1 Moving the PySaxonProcessor before the while loop does not solve the memory leak. The first to suggest that solution admitted they didn't test it.

Looks like two different leaks then, one if you instantiate several PySaxonProcessors, not even doing any XML parsing, the second by doing XML parsing, even with a single PySaxonProcessor.

It looks like a memory leak. I created a bug to track it: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/6391
And the issue is now fixed in the released SaxonC 12.5.

This is not an answer to the question

Perhaps, taken by itself, it does not qualify as an answer. But if it is a memory leak, that is a link to a definitive source of information about the status of that leak and, ultimately, the remedy for it. It will certainly provide OP and anyone who comes across this question in the future with useful information.

There's clearly a failure to properly clean up once the context manager terminates - i.e., PySaxonProcessor.__exit__ isn't doing what it (probably) should do.
You need to contact the developer(s) as this isn't a Python issue per se. You are not doing anything wrong.
The problem can be replicated as follows:
from saxonche import PySaxonProcessor
import psutil

count = 0
process = psutil.Process()
prev = process.memory_info().rss

for _ in range(100):
    with PySaxonProcessor(license=False):
        pass
    if (count := count + 1) % 10 == 0:
        m = process.memory_info().rss
        print(f"{m - prev:,}")
        prev = m

Platform:
macOS 14.4.1
Python 3.12.2
M2

Output:
2,228,224
2,244,608
2,260,992
2,244,608
2,228,224
2,244,608
2,244,608
2,228,224
2,228,224


Yea okay. I was being lazy not wanting to sign up for the Saxon support site because they make you send an introduction email and then you have to wait for an admin to approve you, and I thought I was doing something wrong. But you gave me some confidence and I signed up. If you don't mind, I'll edit your answer to include a link to the bug report once I get an admin to approve me.

@Rainbolt It's important to note that the call to parse_xml() is irrelevant. The memory leak arises merely as a consequence of instantiation of a PySaxonProcessor

The call to parse_xml() is relevant because even if you instantiate the PySaxonProcessor one time before the loop (instead of repeatedly inside of the loop), the code in the question still leaks. It seems like instantiating the PySaxonProcessor costs about 200 KB, whereas the cost of parse_xml() is proportional to the size of the input XML. For larger XML, the leak from parse_xml() dwarfs the leak from instantiating the processor. This is why I included a decently sized XML in the question.

Saxon processor used in a loop without being properly cleaned up. Each time the loop runs, a new instance of PySaxonProcessor is created but it is not being properly released after it's done processing the XML. This can lead to a memory leak as the resources used by the processor are not being released.
Rewrite your code like:
with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:
    while True:
        print('Running once...')
        proc.parse_xml(xml_text=xml_str)
        sleep(1)

I didn't test it, but probabely it will solve your problem.

Edit: From its documentation: __exit__(...) The exit method for the context PySaxonProcessor. Here we release the Jet VM resources. If we have more than one live PySaxonProcessor object the release() method has no effect.
Maybe this is root of the cause.

Probably test it first, then, because guesses aren't answers.

From its documentation: exit(...)
The exit method for the context PySaxonProcessor. Here we release the Jet VM resources. If we have more than one live PySaxonProcessor object the release() method has no effect.

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly So, clearly, the release of Jet VM resources isn't working. There may be other resources that need to be cleaned that are not documented.

Don't tell "me" in a comment, tell everyone by including that information in the answer you wrote. But also: still run the code you're telling someone else to run, to verify that it is, in fact, really the solution (because if it's not, then this is not an answer)

I don't wanna turn this to a chat, but I know I should test it. But this is result of my pip install saxonche and one of many benefits of living in iran :) ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: .../saxonche-12.4.2-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")). It works on some net providers, but not in my current network, irancell
